# Set multiple rows value at once in R

Tags: r, dataframe, indexing

I come from MATLAB so I find some things in R a bit odd. I have two data frames: `data` and `data_target`. I have a boolean array `times` and I want the last columns of the rows corresponding to the indexes where `times == TRUE` to be overwritten with another row. Basically, what I'm trying to do is the following:

`data[times , (ncol(data) - ncol(data_target)+2):(ncol(data))] = data_target[k,-1]`

To be a bit clearer, `(ncol(data) - ncol(data_target)+2):(ncol(data))` actually equals 4, so I want to replace the last 4 values of each row number where `times == TRUE` with the 4 values in `data_target[k,-1]`. In MATLAB, I would use a `repmat()` and everything would work out, but in R I don't know how to solve this.

EDIT: Here's an example of what I'm trying to do. Suppose we have these two data frames:

```
data = 

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
2    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
3    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
4    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
5    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
6    a    b    c    d    e    f    f

data_target = 

  tar1 tar2 tar3 tar4 tar5
1    0    0    0    0    0
2    1    1    1    1    1
3    2    2    2    2    2
4    3    3    3    3    3
5    4    4    4    4    4
```

Assume that `k=3` and `times = c(T,F,F,F,T,F)`. So I want the last 4 elements of the 3rd row of `data_target` to overwrite the corresponding rows in `data`:

```
output = 

  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1    a    b    c    2    2    2    2
2    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
3    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
4    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
5    a    b    c    2    2    2    2
6    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This request cries out for a short example dataset. There should not be 4 values in data_target[k,-1] unless k is a length 4 vector, and I saw nothing to indicate that was an assumption.

Comment: @42- I've added an example.

Comment: Your text is very confusing. You said you wanted to replace the last 4 values, but in your output only 1 value is replaced.

Comment: @RafaelC I was working on it, now it's okay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you want a simple one-liner?

```
data[times, (ncol(data)-4):(ncol(data))] <- data_target[k, (ncol(data_target)-4):(ncol(data_target))]
```

Output

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4 col5 col6 col7
1    a    b    2    2    2    2    2
2    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
3    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
4    a    b    2    2    2    2    2
5    a    b    c    d    e    f    f
6    a    b    2    2    2    2    2
```

---

If you want to make it more readable, you can break it

```
selected_cols = (data_ncols-4):ncol(data)
selected_targ_cols = (ncol(data_target)-4):ncol(data_target)
data[times, selected_cols] <- data_target[k, selected_targ_cols]
```